# What does dim highlighted properties of a JavaScript object signify in Chrome Dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I wanted to know that some properties of the object when we see in scope variables or hover over them(in Chrome developer tools) appears to be dim highlighted. What does it signify?

**//Sample Code**

```
'use strict'
        function myClass(first, second) {
            //            this.pehla = first;
            var private_Var = 'i_am_private_variable';
            this.doosra = second;
            Object.defineProperty(this, 'pehla', { value: '_Haani_Constant', writable: false });

        };

        var instanceOfClass = new myClass('1', '2');

        console.log(instanceOfClass.pehla);
        console.log('Assigning value to pehla');
        console.log("instanceOfClass.pehla = 'SomeOtherText' ");

        try {
            instanceOfClass.pehla = 'SomeOtherText';                                   
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message); 
        }
```

See image for reference

[image]

Comment: Does `myClass` inherit from another object prototype?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Please see the code, I have edited the question

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `writable: false` in the `Object.defineProperty()` call...

Comment: I'm supposing after seeing some of the other demonstrations that there's probably some kind of general "state" that is meant by the dimmed color representation. Wonder if anyone has consulted the documentation...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties that are not enumerable are shown as dimmed. The reason for confusion in another answer is that defineProperty sets enumerable to false by default. Hence the property defined with defineProperty is dimmed unless enumerable is explicitly set to true in the parameters.

Try running the following code to test how different properties look like in DevTools:

```
var test = {
   prop1:"test",
   prop2:"test",
   prop3:"test",
};
Object.defineProperty(test,"other",{
   enumerable:true
});
Object.defineProperty(test,"other1",{
   enumerable:false
});   
Object.defineProperty(test,"other2",{
   writeable:false
});    
Object.defineProperty(test,"other3",{
   configurable:false
});    
console.log(test);
```

And try also running the code below to see which properties are actually enumerable:

```
for (i in test) console.log(i)
```

Comment: Thanks vsevik for the answer

Answer (score 5):

the ones that are dimmed are properties that do not have the default descriptor properties, ie the configurable, writeable, enumerable properties, setting any of these to false will cause the property to be dimmed.

```
var test = {
   prop1:"test",
   prop2:"test",
   prop3:"test",
   prop4:"test",
   prop5:"test",
   prop6:"test",
   prop7:"test",
   prop8:"test",
   prop9:"test",
   prop10:"test",
};
Object.defineProperty(test,"other",{
   enumerable:true
});
Object.defineProperty(test,"other1",{
   enumerable:false
});   
Object.defineProperty(test,"other2",{
   writeable:false
});    
Object.defineProperty(test,"other3",{
   configurable:false
});    
console.log(test);
```

When you expand the object tree you will see `other` as not dimmed, and `other1`,`other2`,`other3` as dimmed

Some exceptions:

```
//other1 will not be dimmed for the following
Object.defineProperty(test,"other1",{
   enumerable:true,
   writeable:false,
   configurable:true
});   
Object.defineProperty(test,"other1",{
   enumerable:true,
   writeable:false,
   configurable:false
});
```

Comment: maybe if either one of them are false

Comment: actually looks like changing any of the descriptor properties to false will do it

Comment: Setting writable to true in the sample code of question still shows the property dim highlighted. I am guessing that setting any of the above mentioned property makes it appear dim highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

By simply echoing `String.prototype` on my company website, it seems dimmed are inherited/pre-generated properties & functions.

[image: e.g. 1]

In this case, `numberFormat`, `regexIndexOf` and `regexLastIndexOf` are functions that we created to extend the class, and reuse later. It also explains why normally in JSON or JS objects you'd usually see them all fully colored.

Another example:

[image: e.g. 2]
[image: e.g. 3]

Comment: There's some other cases apparently where it will dim the color, too: http://jsfiddle.net/m3Zvy/